# What is a "fishtran" fish?

Tags: words, tefilin, translation, kitzur-shulchan-aruch

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch, Siman 10, Sief 1

> .(וְיֵשׁ לִמְשֹׁחַ הָרְצועוֹת תָּדִיר בְּשֻׁמָּן שֶׁיִּהְיוּ
>   שְׁחוֹרִים (וְלֹא יִמְשְׁחֵם בְּשֻׁמָּן דָּג הַנִּקְרָא פִישְׁטְרָאן
>   כִּי הוּא מִדָּג טָמֵא
>
> It is advisable to frequently oil the straps with fat so that they will remain black. They should not be oiled with the oil of the *fishtran* fish since this oil comes from a non-kosher fish.

(Translation via [ArtScroll](http://artscroll.com/Books/9781422608326.html))

What is the *fishtran* fish? I understand this might be closed as it concerns the translation of a word, but I just want to know what this fish is. Obviously the lesson we learn from the above is that the oil of any non-kosher animal may not be used to oil the straps of the tefillin.

Comment: Some Yiddish speakers called [spotted] trout "pistran(g)", but that too is kosher.

Comment: Artscroll doesn’t translate it?

Comment: Btw IMO this is entirely on-topic. The policy isn’t against translating words so much as against translating words irrelevant to a Jewish topic; this doesn’t fit they may description and should therefore be okay.

Comment: @DonielF - Nope, they do not. They just put _fishtran_ there.

Comment: For what it’s worth, I plugged this into Google Translate (Kitzur translates into Yiddish). They wouldn’t translate it.

Comment: @DonielF - Google translate doesn't do such a great job with Yiddish, but FWIW if you type "fischtran" into the German-English, it translates "fish oil".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Uriel Weinreich, ‎Yivo Institute for Jewish Research - 1968 Yiddish English dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=1M6ImTy1xFAC&pg=PA460&lpg=PA460&dq=%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9F&source=bl&ots=jInbeFRtav&sig=oNDrKgB5_nSxivTCgNdZULt1_FU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYk6vqx_XWAhUp5IMKHb6YD-gQ6AEIMjAB#v=onepage&q=%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9F&f=false) פִישְׁטְרָאן is cod liver oil.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cod_liver_oil) cod liver oil is derived from liver of cod fish scientifically known as Gadidae. Gadidae is a non kosher fish per the [OU](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/an-analysis-of-kaskeses-past-and-present-2/)

> Not all “cods” are kosher; the non-kosher burbot mentioned above is
>   classified as a “gadidae”, technically making it a cod.

Based on this I would venture to say that in the times of the Kitzur cod liver oil was only extracted from non kosher species and therefore the Kitzur classifies it as coming from a non kosher fish.

Comment: Interesting, as cod is a kosher species.

Comment: GershonGold, once you added that additional information to your answer, it made it instantly better. Thanks.

Comment: https://yi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9F